# Replacing all strings int java source code

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I am trying to replace every declared String that is inside of a Java formatted source code (using java itself). A source code to remove the strings from may look like this (>...< indicates what should be matched):

```java
package a.b;

import b.a.*;

@SomeAnnotation(>"abc"<)
public class XY extends YZ {

    String s = >"Hello \"World\""<;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(>"Hello World"<);
    }
}
```

Imagine this all stored in one string, possibly without the newlines. I now need a regex that can find all of these. I am having trouble with the escaped quotation marks inside of the strings. My best bet is `".*[^\]"`.

It does not matter whether it will detect these inside of comments, as long as it does not excede the comment.

Comment: Replace it with what, and for what purpose? You are probably better off doing it in an IDE like intellij, where you are able to limit searches to within string literals, rather than trying to do it yourself.

Comment: You should look for some java parsing libraries. Regexp is not suitable instrument for that.

Comment: @Andy turner This is not meant for editing a source file during development. I am working on a programm takes in a string that is in valid java syntax, compiles is and loades the class. Before I can compile the code I have to figure out the class and package name to name the file appropriatly and put it into the correct directory. But I cannot simply search for "class " to find the class name location because there may be some comment or annotation with a string that contains that phrase as well, so I want to remove it first (replace it with "..." or so)

Comment: You simply can't parse Java with a regular expression, because it's not a regular language - exactly as you say "because there may be some comment or annotation". Use the compiler API to inspect the abstract syntax tree.

Comment: That's exactly the problem - I want to compile the string but can only do so by creating a file with the appropriate name. However, I have solved the problem by first parsing the string into java tokens, then filter out the comment tokens and skip to the package / class type token to evaluate name and package.

Answer (score 1):

If you read in the source code in another java application with a BufferedLineReader and check every line you could maybe use the following regex:

```
(?:\>\")(([\w\s]*)(\\"(?!\<)))*(?:\"\<)
```

However you would want to escape all of the backslashes when used inside the java replace method.

e.g.:

```
lineAsString.replace((?:\\>\\")(([\\w\\s]*)(\\\\"(?!\\<)))*(?:\\"\\<),"youReplacementString");
```

Maybe additional escape sequences might be necessary. Also, you might want to add further special chars to be allowed inside the string beside `\w` and `\s`.

I suggest to paste that regex into a regex checker like https://regex101.com/ and your sample code for more explanations.